# Convert VBScript to Powershell

Tags: powershell, vbscript

What is the equivalent of this VBScript:

```
set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")      
set oApp = WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
set oFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

in Windows Powershell?

I am new to PS!

I am not looking for a conversion I am just looking for help!

THanks,

Comment: Start [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee221101.aspx) (first result from google://convert+vbscript+powershell).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3560

Comment: Did you notice the links *below* the (dysfunctional) download link?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I actually got my answer below and accepted, thanks for your answer though!

Comment: Do not attempt to do a 1-to-1 remapping of all things VBScript into PowerShell. Instead, understand *what* the VBScript is doing (not how it does it), then implement that in proper PowerShell. Rewriting VBScript in PowerShell syntax is not improving anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$oShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$oApp = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$oFile = New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject
```

- http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_com.htm